# How to do I equally space the tick marks and rotate the labels on subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, format

**Using Jupyter notebook matplotlib**

I want to equally space the x tick marks, tick frequency (10), and rotate the labels (angle=45) on python matplotlib subplots.

Box 2 has the formatting closest to what I want but the ticks are not equally spaced. I can't get Box 1 x labels to rotate and the tick marks are not equally spaced.

`ax1 = plt.xticks(rotation=45);` --- does not rotate 45 instead it rotates ax2.
I have also tried `sharex=True` in the `plt.subplot` callout

```
plt.style.use('ggplot');  
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2,figsize=(14, 
4),sharex=False,sharey=True);
ax1.set_title('Box1', fontsize=17);
ax2.set_title('Box2', fontsize=17);
ax1.set_ylabel('Items', fontsize=15);

ax1.plot(item_1['var1'],linewidth=3,linestyle='solid',color='yellow');
ax1.plot(item_1['var1_inx'],linewidth=3,linestyle='dashed',color='yellow');
ax2.plot(item_1['var1_inx'],linewidth=3,linestyle='dashed',color='yellow');
ax2.plot(item_2['var1'],linewidth=3,linestyle='solid',color='yellow');
ax1.plot(item_1['var2'],linewidth=3,linestyle='solid',color='blue');
ax1.plot(item_1['var2_inx'],linewidth=3,linestyle='dashed',color='blue');
ax2.plot(item_1['var2_inx'],linewidth=3,linestyle='dashed',color='blue');
ax2.plot(item_2['var2'],linewidth=3,linestyle='solid',color='blue');
monthyearFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m');
ax1 = plt.xticks(rotation=45);
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthyearFmt);

plt.show();
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkVG4.png):[image]

I added an image of the jupyter notebook. The red lines are what ticks to remove.

Comment: Those are two different questions. Each has been answered already, see the respective duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `plt.xticks(...)` will apply those ticks to the most recently defined axes, `ax2` in your case. To fix this, remove the assignment part from `ax1 = plt.xticks(...)` (this is assigning the labels themselves of `ax2` to the variable `ax1` which you don't want) and add the function call under a line where you draw onto the axes that you want. For example,

```py
ax1.plot(item_1['var1'],linewidth=3,linestyle='solid',color='yellow')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

[xticks](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) also takes in lists of ticks and corresponding labels as positional arguments if you want to use those.

Or, optionally, you can use [set_xticks](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html) to affect a specific subplot.

Also, no need for semicolons in python :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of plt.xticks use [autofmt_xdate](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html):

```
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)
```

Comment: This worked on both graphs. How do i set the equal tick spacing ?

Comment: @JohnJohn can't recreate you problem.From what i see you 2 plots are shifted that's why time will shown 2 times